# Using Bootstrap 4 to position the footer below all other contents

Tags: css, html, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a React app where I have a header, container and footer. For animation purpose of route loading, I have to use `position: absolute` on the page rendering part of the container.

The container has a row and 2 columns. One for menu and other is the place where pages are rendered.

Now the problem is since Container second column is `position: absolute` footer goes below to the highest column.

Is there any way to make both columns inside row to have the same height? I am using Bootstrap 4.Any other suggestion is appreciated.

```
<header>..</header>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-4">

 </div>
 <div class="col-8"> //This is positioned absolute
  <div class="page"><div> // class that applies position
 </div>
</div>
<footer>..<footer> //footer goes below any column whichever has more height.
```

**Edit:**
CSS:

```
.page {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

All other classes are Bootstrap.

You can see the issue if you can log in to the below app with any email and any password.

https://healthrecordstack.now.sh/

As in the picture below, the footer overlaps the content. Footer sits just below the menu column as the content column is given a position absolute.

[image]

Comment: can you add your css too?? it would be helpful

Comment: Edited. Added the link to see the issue live

Comment: can you add a screenshot i still don't get you what's your problem is

Answer (score 0):

```
.row
{
  display:flex;
  min-height:80vh;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Tried the same but it just pushes the footer to some extent. If we get a height more than 80, the footer will stay at 80.

Answer (score 0):

You should use table as below example:

```
.table-row{display: table; table-layout: fixed; }
.table-col{display: table-cell; float: none; vertical-align: top; } 

<header>..</header> 
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="table-row"> 
      <div class="col-4 table-col"> </div> 
      <div class="col-8 table-col"> //This is positioned absolute ...... 
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </div>
<footer>..<footer>
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't help. The whole layout got messed.